# How to I get and pass a UICollectionViewCell on a button click

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In a collection view cell I have three buttons and without clicking/ selecting the `UICollectionViewCell`, how can I get the index path of the button that is clicked?

Here is my code so far:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIButton * button = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:10];
    UILabel * labelTitle = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:20];
    UIButton * shareBtn = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:30];
    UIButton * editBtn = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:40];
    [shareBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(shareDoc:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [editBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(editDoc) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}

-(void)shareDoc:(UICollectionViewCell *) senderCell
{
    UICollectionView * collectionView = [self.view viewWithTag:22];
    UICollectionViewCell * cCell = [self.view viewWithTag:11];

    NSIndexPath * indexPath = [collectionView indexPathForCell:cCell];
    NSLog(@"cell: %ld", indexPath.row); //But this just returns 0 every time I clicked on a button.
    NSLog(@"section: %ld", indexPath.section);


}
```

Comment: Try to add tag to the uibutton. And that tag should be indexPath.row.

Comment: It works ok only till the collectionView isn't scrolled. Thanks though, appreciate your help.

Comment: try to adding tap gesture and replace buttons with label or image as per your requirement

Comment: It is always a good idea to subclass your cell and make outlets in your custom cell class and use closures for callbacks. Remember to send cell instance in this callbacks  so that you can get the indexpaths in your main collection view controller through cell instances
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618094-indexpath

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`indexPathForItemAtPoint:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618030-indexpathforitematpoint?language=objc) and using an action method which takes the event as parameter. Something like this:

```
- (IBAction)shareDoc:(id)inSender forEvent:(UIEvent * )inEvent {
    UITouch *theTouch = inEvent.allTouches.anyObject;
    CGPoint thePoint = [theTouch locationInView:self.collectionView];
    IndexPath *theIndexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:thePoint];

    ...
}
```

You should also change the assignment of the Target-Action for the button:

```
[shareBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(shareDoc:forEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Due to [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312184/uicollectionview-indexpathforitematpoint-returning-same-item-despite-scrolling), you should add the `contentOffset`, if the index path is wrong after scrolling:

```
- (IBAction)shareDoc:(id)inSender forEvent:(UIEvent * )inEvent {
    UITouch *theTouch = inEvent.allTouches.anyObject;
    CGPoint theOffset = self.collectionView.contentOffset
    CGPoint thePoint = [theTouch locationInView:self.collectionView];
    IndexPath *theIndexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:CGPointMake(thePoint.x + theOffset.x, thePoint.y + theOffset.y)];

    ...
}
```

But that seems very strange to me.

Comment: Thanks for your help @clemens. But this hasn't yet solved my problem.

Comment: @Prashant: `theIndexPath` contains the index path of the cell which contains the button. What are you missing?

Comment: It works ok only till the collectionView isn't scrolled.

Comment: @Prashant: This is very strange. Due to [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312184/uicollectionview-indexpathforitematpoint-returning-same-item-despite-scrolling) you should add the `contentOffset` to the point. I've extended my post.

Answer (score 1):

U can try this，custom your cell or use tag （whatever）to ensure indexpath，then use UIResponder to pass your SEL. for example,

```
@interface UIResponder (PassAction)

- (void)passAction:(NSString *)actionName otherInfo:(NSDictionary *)otherInfo;

@end
```

And U can trigger in your cell , like this:

```
[self passAction:NSStringFromClass([cell class]) userInfo:@{@"Tag":@(cell.tag)}];
```

in controller , implement like this:

```
- (void) passAction:(NSString *)eventName otherInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
    NSLog(@"success");
}
```

Comment: I just did that. Worked!